# How to Find Intersections with Ellipses in PGF/TikZ

Tags: latex, intersection, ellipse, tikz, pgf

I am trying to display a sphere in PGF/TikZ to illustrate the idea of great circles.

The code for my current result is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzfading[name=fade right,
left color=transparent!20,
right color=transparent!90]

\tikzfading[name=fade out,
inner color=transparent!100,
outer color=transparent!10]

\tikzfading[name=fade right gc,
left color=transparent!0,
right color=transparent!70]

\draw [<->, dashed] (0,-5) -- (0,5); % y-axis
\draw [->, dashed] (0, 0) -- (20:5); % x-axis
\draw [->, dashed] (0, 0) -- (200:5); % x-axis
\draw [->, dashed] (0, 0) -- (340:5); % z-axis
\draw [->, dashed] (0, 0) -- (160:5); % z-axis

\fill [color=cyan, opacity=0.15, path fading=fade out] (0,0) circle (4cm); % bounding circle
\fill [color=cyan, opacity=0.25, path fading=fade right, fading angle=90] (0,0) ellipse (4cm and 1cm); % x-y-axis area

% great circle 1
\draw [rotate=-40, color=red, path fading=fade right gc, fading angle=40] (0,0) ellipse (4cm and 1cm);

% great circle 2
\draw[rotate=5, color=red, path fading=fade right gc, fading angle=5] (0,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 4cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I

1. find the two points of intersection of the two red ellipses (commented as great circle 1 and 2),
2. find the point of intersection of a line (originating at the center (0,0)) with a ellipse, and
3. place a little circle or rectangle there?

Placing a little circle or rectangle there is not an issue.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out section 4.1.4. of the [TikZ and PGF manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), titled "The Intersection of the Circles."  You need to use the `intersections` library, which allows you to use the `name intersections` key, as in `\path [name intersections={of=path 1 and path 2}] ;`.  To use this, you'll need to use the `name path` key, as in `\draw [name path = y axis, <->, dashed] (0,-5) -- (0,5) ; % y-axis`.  Accessing the intersections seems to vary between versions; my local copy of the manual has different instructions from the one I linked you to.  However, at least on my version, you then access the intersections with `(intersection-1)`, `(intersection-2)`, etc.  To get circles at each intersection in your example, then, I would change your code to look like the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzfading[ name        = fade right
             , left color  = transparent!20
             , right color = transparent!90 ]

  \tikzfading[name         = fade out
             , inner color = transparent!100
             , outer color = transparent!10 ]

  \tikzfading[name         = fade right gc
             , left color  = transparent!0
             , right color = transparent!70]

  \draw [name path = y  axis, <->, dashed] (0,-5) -- (0,5)   ; % y-axis
  \draw [name path = x- axis,  ->, dashed] (0, 0) -- (20:5)  ; % x-axis
  \draw [name path = x+ axis,  ->, dashed] (0, 0) -- (200:5) ; % x-axis
  \draw [name path = z+ axis,  ->, dashed] (0, 0) -- (340:5) ; % z-axis
  \draw [name path = z- axis,  ->, dashed] (0, 0) -- (160:5) ; % z-axis

  % bounding circle
  \fill [color=cyan, opacity=0.15, path fading=fade out]
        (0,0) circle (4cm) ;

  % x-y-axis area
  \fill [color=cyan, opacity=0.25, path fading=fade right, fading angle=90]
        (0,0) ellipse (4cm and 1cm);

  % great circle 1
  \draw [ name path    = great circle 1
        , rotate       = -40
        , color        = red
        , path fading  = fade right gc
        , fading angle = 40]
        (0,0) ellipse (4cm and 1cm);

  % great circle 2
  \draw [ name path    = great circle 2
        , rotate       = 5
        , color        = red
        , path fading  = fade right gc
        , fading angle = 5]
        (0,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 4cm);

  % Intersections
  \path [name intersections={of=great circle 1 and great circle 2}] ;
  \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \fill [color=red] (intersection-\i) circle (2pt) ;

  \path [name intersections={of=y axis and great circle 1}] ;
  \fill (intersection-1) circle (2pt) ;
  \fill (intersection-2) circle (2pt) ;
  \path [name intersections={of=y axis and great circle 2}] ;
  \fill (intersection-1) circle (2pt) ;
  \fill (intersection-2) circle (2pt) ;

  \foreach \a in {x,z} {
    \foreach \ss in {+,-} {
      \def\s.{\ss} % Otherwise the space in `\a\s axis` would get gobbled.
      \path [name intersections={of=\a\s. axis and great circle 1}] ;
      \fill (intersection-1) circle (2pt) ;
      \path [name intersections={of=\a\s. axis and great circle 2}] ;
      \fill (intersection-1) circle (2pt) ;
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Other than the reformatting (to avoid the horizontal scroll bar), all I have changed of your existing code is to add the `name path` key to your axes and great circles.  I then added the intersections code, which should be relatively self-explanatory.  Remember to `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}` first, and everything should work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. As far as I understand I need to have the latest developer version from the CVS, since intersection is not included in the "regular" pgf-2.00.tar.gz. Since I am experiencing some problems with the installation I will get back as soon as that works.

Comment: This (second post = first reply) http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=5687 might be useful to many other running MikTex.